# C# - JSON to Key Value & vice versa

Tags: c#, json

I am fetching a string from a JSON file & want to convert it to Key-Value pair.

I am using JSON.NET for the same.

I know I can deserialize a List using:

```
List<JsonClass> jsonFileComments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonClass>>(json);
```

And I can Deserialize a Array using:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

But as my JSON string contains Lists & Arrays in single file only. The sequence is like:

```
{
    List,
    List,
    List,
    Array,
    List, 
    Array,
    List 
}
```

Can you tell me how can I deserialize it using single way.

Other way is I need to separate out the Arrays & work on separately. And again while Serializing I need to work that stuff.

Comment: Most of the time you'd deserialize a JSON string into a specific C# type. Can you show the JSON you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one way would be to use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)(The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking.)?

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

Comment: Hi Margus, This dynamic keyword works in Windows Application but when I went to Web Application where I want to use it actually, it throws error saying "Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain."....Any suggestion?

Comment: @SanjayAdsure Are you running your application on pre .net4.0 ? You can try to load it into a different appdomain (http://www.bryancook.net/2010/02/running-code-in-separate-appdomain.html)

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 with SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code block helps. I'm assuming you have jSon object & you need to parse through it:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(yourJsonData);
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray textArray = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)o["yourArray"];
if (textArray.Count > 0)
{
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.Count; i++)
{//do something}
}
```